# How to import apache libraries on my inteliJ project

Tags: java, apache, intellij-idea, libraries

My programming colleague sent me a Java project but it's using some apache libraries:

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser;
...
```

How do I install this libraries so I can compile the project?

Comment: Is it an Ant project, Maven project, or something else?

Comment: Go to project structure, click on libraries, click the + button, click from maven and then add in the artifact id

Comment: What id uses apache.commons? Can't find it

Answer (score 5):

Option 1:

File > Project Structure > Libraries > + > from maven > search for `commons-cli`

Option 2:

[Download jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar) and go to File > Project Structure > Libraries > + > from Java > select your jar file

Option 3:

Setup your project with some build tool (Maven, Gradle and etc.) and grab your dependency [from here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2)

Comment: Thanks, I added it from the jar